# Google Indexing pages generated by URL Parameters

Tags: magento2.2.7, google

So, my `robots.txt` explicitly says not to crawl any URLs containing a URL Parameter. And that works as expected.

However, Google Search Console is moaning with the following issue:

> Indexed, though blocked by robots.txt
>
> Affected Pages 1.88k

I would like to know if I missed a setting in Magento that allows me to set auto-generated pages based on **URL Parameters** and **Page Numbers** to `NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW` whilst leaving the rest of the site set to `INDEX, FOLLOW`.

If Magento doesn't support this out-the-box, what options do I have?